# How to change the display of an empty string in mysql command line tool?

Tags: mysql, innodb, select, null, varchar

I'm maintaining a database with InnoDB tables.
These tables have some columns of type (from show create table):

```
`val0` varchar(30) default NULL,
`val1` varchar(30) default NULL,
etc...
```

From the mysql command line I am searching for NULL entries in these tables.

Now I SELECTed some rows where `val0 IS NULL AND val1 = ''` (empty string), but the mysql command line shows both values as

```
+------+------+
| val0 | val1 |
+------+------+
| NULL | NULL |
+------+------+
```

Apparently this is confusing me. **Is this behavior intentional? Is there a method to define how empty strings are displayed?**

---

**EDIT :**

I should mention that STRICT MODE (see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html)) seems to be enabled.

The query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE val0 IS NULL AND val1 = '';
```

finds the row above. The query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE val0 IS NULL AND val1 IS NULL;
```

doesn't find that row. Still the '' is displayed as 'NULL'. How do I change that?

Server version is "5.0.22-log".

---

**EDIT 2 :**

Here is the full (anonymized) SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `val0` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val1` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val2` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val3` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val4` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val5` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val6` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val7` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val8` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `val9` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) default '0',
  UNIQUE KEY `idtime` (`id`,`time`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  CONSTRAINT `mytable_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `idtable` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here are my queries:

```
select * from mytable where val1 is null limit 1;
```

-> no result

```
select * from mytable where val1 = '' limit 1;
```

result:

```
+-----+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| id  | time       | val0 | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val8 | val9 | status |
+-----+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| 300 | 1346855716 | 0    | NULL | 42   | 4711 | blib | blub | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |      5 |
+-----+------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+--------+
```

fun fact: These last four NULLs are actually the string "NULL". (I'm only maintaining this system, I didn't build it...)

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: @ypercube server version: 5.0.22-log

Comment: Looks like the first comment here: http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html#1_1 - "If you define a column as NOT NULL and query the table with a IS NULL condition this should return no rows. But MySQL knows that the column cannot be NULL, thus simply "optimizes" the IS NULL condition away and returns all rows!!!!"

Comment: @JohnP But the columns are not defined as NOT NULL. They even have NULL as default value.

Comment: Does  `select null val0,'' val1` also display the same output as show in your post (`NULL | NULL`)?

Comment: I think the following title would be more suitable: How to change the display of an empty string in mysql command line tool?

Comment: @miracle173 Title: Good point, I changed it. Select: No, this displays as val0: NULL, val1: ''. So I guess this has to do with the table structure or with InnoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bug #20067 empty string returns NULL as dispalyed value](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20067)

This bug is possibly fixed 5.0.23. Look at the document referenced by the above page.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll have to ask the client to update or I'll just live with it then.